# Chip Group Second Row Overlaps

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, material-components-android

Right now I have a chip group with 4 chips and it is on the right size of a layout (meaning it doesn't get the entire screen width), when the text in the fourth chip gets too long it moves it to the next row.
I added this code:

```
app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="0dp"
```

To make the space in between the chips smaller because before the space was really big, but now the space is too small. The padding or margins don't work either, but I could be doing something wrong.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="312dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/line2">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/tag1"
                style="@style/Colors_Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Tag1"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="0dp" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/tag2"
                style="@style/Colors_Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Tag2"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="0dp" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/tag3"
                style="@style/Colors_Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Tag3"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="0dp" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/tag4"
                style="@style/Colors_Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Tag4"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="0dp" />
        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Picture of my chip group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nDtB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had made a separate style component to design the chips. Instead of having the `chipMinTouchTargetSize` in the layout file, I included it in the style section. Then I added the `app:chipSpacingVertical="5dp"` to the chip group parent. And it worked.

Style:

```
<style name="Colors_Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
    <item name="chipCornerRadius">12dp</item>
    <item name="chipMinHeight">24dp</item>
    <item name="chipMinTouchTargetSize">5dp</item>
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/honeyBright</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Layout

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            app:chipSpacingVertical="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/tag1"
                style="@style/Colors_Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tag1"
                android:textSize="11sp" />
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Here is what it looks like now: [Correct Chip Group Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvE2F.png)